# The main method isn't found in my GUI class

Tags: java, user-interface, main-method

I've assembled a basic GUI but the debugger says there is no main method even though there is a `static void main(String[] args)` here is my code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GUI implements ActionListener {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI();
    }

    public GUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton(String.valueOf(Game.Compounds));
        button.addActionListener(this);

        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 10, 30));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(button);

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("GUI");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Game.Compounds = Game.Compounds + Game.CPC;
    }
}
```

What is wrong with it

Comment: `main()` must be public.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the "public" modifier. The signature of main method is: `public static void main(String [] args)`

Answer (score 0):

java always search the main function to start the application.

but you did a little mistake, main should be public, so change the declaration like this `public static void main(String[] args)`

modify your code like below:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GUI implements ActionListener {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI();
    }

    public GUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton(String.valueOf(Game.Compounds));
        button.addActionListener(this);

        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 10, 30));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(button);

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("GUI");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Game.Compounds = Game.Compounds + Game.CPC;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But if you don't specify anything it should be public by def

Comment: It can be a comment.